# CSS color won't change

Tags: css, colors, css-selectors

I want my nav li to be light blue when unselected and white with a white bar underneath when selected. For some reason, I can change anything else about both the selected and unselected li items (size, background color, etc.; in the same selector or a different one--works either way), but only the selected li's font color can be changed. The unselected items stay white.

I've checked the dev tools for a conflict overriding the light blue color; everything says it should be light blue. I've tried adjusting the specificity of the selector, moving the color change to a different selector, checking for misplaced semicolons. I've also tried hard refreshing the page and checking it in a different browser. I imagine I'm making some kind of obvious mistake, but I can't figure out why the inactive items just stay white.

This is the nav HTML:

```css
  element.style {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) .nav-destinations li.inactive-mini {
  color: var(--light-blue);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) .nav-destinations li {
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.nav-destinations li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 24px;
}

.nav-text1,
.nav-text2 {
  font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', sans;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 2.7px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

user agent stylesheet li {
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) .nav-destinations ul {
  text-align: center;
}

user agent stylesheet ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
}

:root {
  --dark-blue: #0B0D17;
  --light-blue: #D0D6F9;
  --white: #FFFFFF;
```

```html
<div id="destination-nav" class="nav-destinations">
  <ul id="destination-nav-ul">
    <li id='moon' class="nav-text2 active-mini">MOON</li>
    <li id="mars" class="nav-text2 inactive-mini"><a href="destination-mars.html">MARS</a></li>
    <li id="europa" class="nav-text2 inactive-mini"><a href="destination-europa.html">EUROPA</a></li>
    <li id="titan" class="nav-text2 inactive-mini"><a href="destination-titan.html">TITAN</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: I've converted your posted HTML and CSS into a running Snippet, I haven't edited the CSS (though there is an obvious typo, the missing `}` for the `:root` rules), so the `.element` seems not to apply (I know you took it from the Inspector, instead of your CSS - for reasons that are unclear to me - but could you correct the code so it accurately reproduces the CSS you've put together?

Comment: Anchor elements don't inherit color. Maybe you're trying to change the color property of the parent li element, and that won't work...